# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: mallet path

Tags: python, windows, file, path, mallet

So this code was working before now I'm getting this error - please help :(

```html
mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'

ldamallet_test = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus_test, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary_test)
```

[image: Error message]

[image: This mallet.bat file I'm referencing no longer opens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your home directory for Mallet is not set up properly.  Even though you have the path to the binary set as a variable, you still must define the environment variable that contains the source of where Mallet is located:

```
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:\\mallet\\mallet-2.0.8'

mallet_path = 'C:\\mallet\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet'
ldamallet_test = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus_test, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary_test)
```

Take note that you don't need to add the `.bat` extension as Windows should execute this natively as it knows it's a batch file.  As a final note, you should use double backslashes (`\\`) for the path separator in Windows.  Not doing this depending on what version of Windows you're using may give unexpected behaviour.  If you want to avoid headaches, try using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) which will provide the right path separator for you regardless of the OS:

```
mallet_path = os.path.join('C:', 'mallet', 'mallet-2.0.8', 'bin', 'mallet')
```

Comment: The ".bat" file extension can be assumed when executing via the CMD shell (e.g. using `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True`) because it's in the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Otherwise it cannot be assumed. This is a shell behavior, not general to Windows. `CreateProcessW` supports executing batch scripts directly via the `ComSpec` shell, but the ".bat" or ".cmd" extension has to be included. Otherwise it only assumes ".exe" as the file extension, and tries to execute any file it finds as a binary image.